# Encuesta en Django

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy haciendo una encuesta, donde cada pregunta almacenada en la base de datos deberia aparecer y a continuacion cada una de las opciones (tambien de la base de datos) con un checkbox, pero cuando cargo la pagina web, ciertamente aparecen todas las preguntas, solo que cada pregunta tiene todas las opciones guardadas en la BD, no solo las q tiene asignada cada una. Quiero q cada pregunta aparezca unicamente con las opciones asociadas.

este es el html:

```
{%extends "C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\Django\ProyectoDjangoWeb\ProyectoDjangoApp\Templates\ProyectoDjangoApp\Base.html"%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
        <h1 style="margin-left: 590px; color: cornsilk; text-shadow: rgb(39, 49, 49) 2px 2px 5px;">Encuestas</h1>
        <p></p>
    <article style="color: cornsilk; background-color:  rgb(153, 152, 160); width: 70%; margin:auto; border-radius: 1%;">
{% if encuesta %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in encuesta %}
        <p style="text-align:center;">{{question.pregunta}}</p>
        {% for choice in opcion %}
        <table style="display: inline;padding: 40px; color: cornsilk;">
            <tr><td> {{choice.opciones}} <input type="checkbox" name="opciones"></td></tr>
        </table>
        {% endfor%}
    
        <p></p>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar información" style="margin-left: 370px;">
    <p></p>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Sin encuestas disponibles</p>
{% endif %}
</article>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

---

### Estos son los modelos

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import create_many_to_many_intermediary_model


class Choice(models.Model):
    opciones = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)    
    votos = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name= "Opción" 
            verbose_name_plural= "Opciones"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.opciones

class Encuesta(models.Model):
    pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    opciones = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)#Trae las opciones de la tabla Choice, como muchos a muchos
    publicado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)#auto_now_add permite guardar la fecha instantaneamente

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= "encuesta" 
        verbose_name_plural= "encuestas"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pregunta
```

---

### y estos son las vistas

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Encuesta, Choice
from django.shortcuts import render


def encuesta(request):
    encuesta=Encuesta.objects.all()
    Opcion=Choice.objects.all()
    return render(request, "AppPoll/Poll.html", {"encuesta":encuesta, "opcion": Opcion})
```

Comment: Entonces...¿Cual es tu pregunta? ¿Sale error? ¿Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Cuando cargo el html aparecen todas las opciones guardas en la base de datos para cada una de las preguntas, cuando lo que quiero es q solo salgan las opciones asociadas a cada pregunta.

Comment: Parece que en la vista estás incluyendo todas las respuestas y no solo las vinculadas a la encuesta (`Opcion=Choice.objects.all()`). Deberías utilizar solo encuesta y en la plantilla los objetos relacionados (p.e. encuesta.choices.all)